# Unable to load a website in WebView inside FlipView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm trying to open a website inside the FlipView control in Windows Store application. Here is my code:

```
protected override async void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    var template = flipView.ItemTemplate;
    var grid = (Grid)template.LoadContent();
    var webView = (WebView)grid.Children[0];

    webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
}

private void contentView_LoadCompleted_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var template = flipView.ItemTemplate;
    var grid = (Grid)template.LoadContent();
    var webView = (WebView)grid.Children[0];
    webView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

and XAML:

```
  <FlipView
        x:Name="flipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">

        <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,137,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="Output">
                            <WebView x:Name="WebView1" Visibility="Collapsed" LoadCompleted="contentView_LoadCompleted_1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BlockingRect"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

Maybe someone faced this problem earlier? What's the solution?

Answer (score 3):

The callisto WebViewExtension https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/WebViewExtension is the best way I've found to bind WebView content into a FlipView.

In the default usage there are still issues with some touch (tap specifically) interactions within the WebView items as the FlipView is handling those instead of letting them fall through to the WebView. Thus causing links within the WebView to not be able to be interacted with. This is not an issue when using a mouse though as clicks fall through to the WebView.

Comment: Works very well and it is easy to setup the binding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First Give Uniq Name To your Framework Controll  lıke  `x:Name="ItemDetailPageWebView"`
   Than copy and Past At Code Behind  What ı Wright Down Below

XAML:

```
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView"
       AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
       AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
       TabIndex="1" Grid.Row="1"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"   
       Loaded="ItemDetailPageflipView_Loaded">
              <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <Grid>       
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" >
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Height="628" Width="2755">
                                  <WebView x:Name="ItemDetailPageWebView" Height="443" Margin="53,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="435" />
                            </StackPanel>
                      </ScrollViewer>
                 </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

C# :

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            public static T FindVisualChildByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string name) where T : DependencyObject
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                    string controlName = child.GetValue(Control.NameProperty) as string;
                    if (controlName == name)
                    {
                        return child as T;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        T result = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name);
                        if (result != null)
                            return result;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            //Here FlipView Loaded Event 
            private void ItemDetailPageflipView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                WebView ItemDetailPageWebView = FindVisualChildByName<WebView>(this.flipView, "ItemDetailPageWebView");
                ItemDetailPageWebView.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
            }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Give me a + if I helped And Click Answer.     Happy coding ;)